# GA Store Visits in BigQuery?

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

This is maybe the wrong place to ask that, feel free to guide me :)

Do you know guys, if their is a way to get the data "store visits" in BigQuery, related with the GA360 association Beta Feature?

Of course considering the feature is enabled for the company :)

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer to [official documentation](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/7573498?hl=en), in `Limits and caveats` you can find :

> The following are currently not supported:
>
> - Segmentation
> - Audiences and Remarketing
> - **BigQuery Export**
> - Custom reports
> - Multi-Channel Funnels and Attribution reports

Hope it is helpful.